# How to find files with invalid timestamps on Windows

Tags: windows, timestamp

I have got a number of files on a NTFS partition that contain bogus 'modified' timestamps (for example 12/03/1804).

I have tried to use enter `System.DateModified:<01/01/1970` into the Windows search field (or alternatively `datemodified:<01/01/1970`, but these filters don't show the files. Windows does in these cases appear to look at their creation time stamp instead, which is different and correct in my case.

Is there another way to get Windows search to show those files? Or a command line tool?

Comment: In Details view of Search results (search for all files), can't you add the Date Modified column and sort by it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_%28software%29) from VoidTools for this. It lists all files on drives and the list can be sorted by create, modify, and access date.

Comment: How does it cope with files that have a modification date of year 1804?

Comment: Recently ran into this, Void Tools' Everything stops responding when sorting by creation date so I can't identify the file with the invalid date. Still a good tool for most other file tracking tasks.